# Portaudio can only display one host API (audio driver) on Windows

Tags: c++, audio, portaudio

I'm building an app that uses portaudio to handle audio playback and recording. I want to let the user be able to choose both the host API or audio driver and output device. However, Pa_GetHostApiCount() only returns one audio driver on my Windows machine (MME) even though I also have ASIO, Direct Sound and WASAPI installed.
Is there any previous configuration needed for Portaudio to display the rest of audio drivers in my machine? Ideally, if ASIO is installed I would like to set that up as the default host API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.